# Unable to pass nodejs variable into JSON string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How can I pass `sns_NameSpace` variable into the `payload`? I'm getting the error `Unrecognized token sns_NameSpace`. I tried to stringfy using JSON and yet still I get the same error.

`Error:`

```
   "errorMessage": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token 'sns_NameSpace': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{ \"Host\": sns_NameSpace, \"Key\": sns_key, \"Value\": \"1\"}\"; line: 1, column: 25]",
```

`code:`

```
   var sns_NameSpace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;
   var sns_NameSpace = JSON.stringify(sns_NameSpace.replace("/", "_"));
   var sns_key = JSON.stringify(sns_ApiId + '_' + sns_MetricName);

  var params = {
    FunctionName: 'zabbixPy', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    Payload: '{ "Host": sns_NameSpace, "Key": sns_key, "Value": "1"}'
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid string you should be able to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this.

EX:

```
var params = {
    ...
    Payload: `{ "Host": ${sns_NameSpace}, "Key": ${sns_key}, "Value": "1"}`
};
```

Also, I'd recommend using different variable names instead of defining, then re-defining `sns_nameSpace`.

Comment: Alright testing this. Is JSON.Stringify necessary for SNS_Namespace as show in second line?

Comment: is it a string already

Comment: I'm still getting the unrecongized token error. But `$` seems to be problem. Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token '$': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{ \"Host\": ${sns_hostname}, \"Key\": ${sns_key}, \"Value\": \"1\"}\"; line: 1, column: 13]",

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I would @Codebling's solution #1

Comment: For future readers, if you see an error like `Unrecognized token '$'`, it's likely that you need to use backtick (`\``) instead of single or double quotes (`'`, `"`) around your string. Another possibility is that you are using a version of Node.js older than 4.0.0 or a browser from 2013-2014

Answer (score 0):

This question should be renamed "How do I concatenate a variable and a string?". The issue is on your "Payload" line.

#### Problem: variable being interpreted literally

Here is the string that is not working:

```js
'{ "Host": sns_NameSpace, "Key": sns_key, "Value": "1"}'
```

As you can see from the error message, `sns_NameSpace` is not being replaced and so is being interpreted literally, as an invalid JSON token.

#### Solution 1: string concatenation

One can concatenate strings using the [*string concatenation operator* (**+**)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition)

```js
'{ "Host": ' + sns_NameSpace + ', "Key": ' + sns_key + ', "Value": "1"}'
```

#### Solution 2: template strings

Or can use [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to as so:

```js
`{ "Host": ${sns_NameSpace}, "Key": ${sns_key}, "Value": "1"}`
```

Please note that the template string uses ` (backtick), not ' (single quote)

Comment: Template string isn't working. I get the same error. Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token '$': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (byte[])\"{ \"Host\": ${sns_hostname}, \"Key\": ${sns_key}, \"Value\": \"1\"}\"; line: 1, column: 13]",

Comment: Please note that this is a backtick, not a single quote

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot more straight-forward to build the object in JS and *then* stringify it, instead of stringifying individual parts and having literal JSON pieces in the string:

```js
var sns_NameSpace = sns.Trigger.Namespace;
var sns_NameSpace = JSON.stringify(sns_NameSpace.replace("/", "_"));
var sns_key = JSON.stringify(sns_ApiId + '_' + sns_MetricName);
var params = {
  FunctionName: 'zabbixPy', // the lambda function we are going to invoke
  InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
  LogType: 'Tail',
  Payload: JSON.stringify({
    Host: sns_NameSpace.replace('/', '_'),
    Key: sns_ApiId + '_' + sns_MetricName,
    Value: 1
  })
};
```